# android is not defined - NativeScript timers.js

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm getting the 'android is not defined' error when trying to run a build for Android.

I don't define or use the variable `android`, but the error points towards that.

It seems to be triggered by timers.js, which I assume is from `tns-core-modules/timer` which I am using.

I load this using the following line:

`const timerModule = require("tns-core-modules/timer");`

Do you need to load anything else for it to work on Android?

It only occurs when I run a release build - not a debug build.

```
[19-10-06 12:25:02.406] (CLI) /App/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/_embedded_script_.js:37
;(global.webpackJsonp=global.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[1],[function(e,t,r){(function(e){Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0});var n=r(53),i=r(13),o=r(82),a=r(4),s=r(89),l=r(3),u=r(2),c=r(17);!function __export(e){for(var r in e)t.hasOwnProperty(r)||(t[r]=e[r])}(r(53));var p,d,f="_domId",h=c.default(function(){return parseInt(u.device.sdkVersion)}),g=new Map;function initializeDialogFragment(){if(!d){var t=function(t){__extends(DialogImpl,t);function DialogImpl(r,n,i){var o=t.call(this,n,i)||this;o.fragment=r;return e.__native(o)}DialogImpl.prototype.onDetachedFromWindow=function(){t.prototype.onDetachedFromWindow.call(this);this.fragment=null};DialogImpl.prototype.onBackPressed=function(){var e=this.fragment.owner,r={eventName:"activityBackPressed",object:e,activity:e._context,cancel:!1};l.android.notify(r);if(!r.cancel){e.notify(r);r.cancel||e.onBackPressed()||t.protot
ReferenceError: android is not defined
    at createHandlerAndGetId (/App/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/_embedded_script_.js:37:378802)
    at setInterval (/App/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/_embedded_script_.js:37:379422)
    at Storage.tick (/App/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:125:21)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
[19-10-06 12:25:02.445] Build failed. Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you do not import timer? Also may I know why you are importing timer, as it's already a global module.

Comment: @Manoj the error still seems to occur if I don't import it. I was importing because the docs suggested I needed to (https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/timer). The release build works fine for iOS and it works fine in debug mode on Android

Comment: @Manoj I still get the issue if I empty all .vue files - so I guess that means it's something which is being bundled up rather than explicitly called

Comment: The issue goes away with I disable snapshots - but I want to keep them ideally